# Como gerar e acessar dinamicamente div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou tentando montar uma preview de imagens, mas preciso que cada uma seja independente, estou enfrentando um problema do qual não consigo resolver. Preciso acessar id's dinamicamente com o JQuery, alguém pode dar uma luz?

Código abaixo para análise:

```
<div id="container_principal">

                                <div class="box_principal">
                                    <div id="enviado_por">Enviador por: Usuario 1</div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_1"></div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_2"></div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_3"></div>
                                    <div id="btn_abrir_descricao">Ver Descrição</div>
                                    <div id="descricao">fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds aaa</div>   
                                </div>

                                <div class="box_principal">
                                    <div id="enviado_por">Enviador por: Usuario 2</div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_1"></div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_2"></div>
                                    <div id="img_foto_3"></div>
                                    <div id="btn_abrir_descricao">Ver Descrição</div>
                                    <div id="descricao">fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds aaa</div>   
                                </div>
</div>
```

Ai no caso seriam várias imagens e no jquery eu precisava fazer com que cada uma fosse única e que eu pudesse acessar elas pelo id:

Ai por exemplo tenho ali o id "descrição", no jquery teria o click do botao descrição e quando fosse abrir, teria que abrir independente das outras box, não sei explicar direito kkkkk, mas gostaria de gerar dinamicamente e poder acessar cada um independente no jquery. Como faço isso? alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Como estás a gerar esse HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fábio,

Com jQuery não precisa necessáriamente trabalhar com os ids. Neste caso, você pode usar algo em comum para selecionar os elementos. 
(inclusive no seu exemplo não está certo declarar o mesmo id mais de uma vez)

Fiz algumas mudanças no seu html:

1. Removi os ids dos elementos "descrição"
2. Troquei a div do ver destalhes para um elemento `a` (coloquei dois a, porque um tem o exemplo animado e outro não).
3. Inseri atributos comuns no objetos que serão manipulados, neste caso utilizei classes do css como seletor
4. Registrei os eventos de clique no jQuery

Perceba que a manipulação dos elementos foi sem usar IDS e sim atributos em comum. Não precisaria ser necessariamente a classe, poderia ser qualquer outro seletor jQuery.

```html
<html>
<body>

    <div id="container_principal">

        <div class="box_principal">
            <div id="enviado_por">Enviador por: Usuario 1</div>
            <div id="img_foto_1"></div>
            <div id="img_foto_2"></div>
            <div id="img_foto_3"></div>
            <a href="#" class="btn-descricao">Ver/ocultar Descrição</a><br />
            <a href="#" class="btn-descricao2">Ver/ocultar Descrição com animação</a>
            <div class="descricao" style="display: none">fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds aaa</div>
        </div>

        <div class="box_principal">
            <div id="enviado_por">Enviador por: Usuario 2</div>
            <div id="img_foto_1"></div>
            <div id="img_foto_2"></div>
            <div id="img_foto_3"></div>
            <a href="#" class="btn-descricao">Ver/ocultar Descrição</a><br />
            <a href="#" class="btn-descricao2">Ver/ocultar Descrição com animação</a>
            <div class="descricao" style="display: none">fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds fddsfdsdsffds aaa</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>

        $(".btn-descricao").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Evita que o <a> execute o location.
// A função siblings() busca o elemento "irmão" do objeto clicado.
// A função toggle() exibe o objeto se estiver oculto ou oculta o objeto se estiver visivel.
            $(e.currentTarget).siblings('.descricao').toggle(); 
        });

        $(".btn-descricao2").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //Evita que o <a> execute o location.
// A função siblings() busca o elemento "irmão" do objeto clicado.
// A função slideToggle() faz a mesma coisa que a função toggle(), mas com a animação estilo "slide"
            $(e.currentTarget).siblings('.descricao').slideToggle();
        })

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, obrigado Ericson, com o evento .on("click, function)